# In bash How do I echo out a $ without reading it as a variable?

Tags: bash

i have been trying to teach my siblings basic bash for a while and then i decided to make a program in bash on how to do bash. but when it comes to something with variables like a simple while loop like this to echo out to teach them how it looks and such

```
echo "var=1
while [ $var == 1 ]; do
read item
$item
done
t=2"
```

This was a the first teaching on while loops which teaches how while loop goes around and around till broken by a break or isn't following the argument anymore and thus getting t = 2 (to get to the next level). but every time I echo I will get

```
var=1
while [ 1 == 1]; do
read item

done
t=2
```

So is there a way to echo the dollar sign. Without me having to say in my program that i couldn't echo a dollar sign remember to put dollar sign in front of this. because i already know that will cause problems on where these things go.

Thank you in advanced for all who answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wherever you have `$VAR`, replace it with `\$VAR`. In a nutshell, \ is an escape character that will 'ignore' special characters following it.

So in your case, use `\$item`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [heredoc](/questions/tagged/heredoc):

```
cat <<'XXX'
var=1
while [ $var == 1 ]; do
read item
$item
done
t=2
XXX
```

Output:

```
var=1
while [ $var == 1 ]; do
read item
$item
done
t=2
```

Unfortunately `cat` is an external utility. But it can be made without external call:

```
while read -r x; do echo "$x"; done <<'XXX'
var=1
while [ $var == 1 ]; do
read item
$item
done
t=2
XXX
```

`-r` is used in `read` to avoid treating backslash as escape character.

Or You can also use `echo` with single quotation mark:

```
echo 'var=1
while [ $var == 1 ]; do
read item
$item
done
t=2'
```

And of course the already mentioned double qoutation mark and escape the `$` sign.

Comment: ha! I thought of heredoc too... :) +1

Comment: @Kent: Not the nicest solution and `cat` is not a built-in function. Either escape (backslash or using single quotation mark) seems to be better.

Comment: what came up first was of course single quote and escape. but they were answered here already, I thought heredoc with single quote could work too, and found in your answer as well....

Comment: very cool i give props for explaining how it works i will probably use this.

Answer (score 2):

Backslash it.

```
echo "var=1
while [ \$var == 1 ]; do
read item
\$item
done
t=2"
```